# Upgrading from Pi B+ to Pi v2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have a new Raspberry Pi v2 unit and I'm trying to use an SD card image from one of my other Raspberry Pi B+ units.  When I insert the Pi B+ card into the Pi v2 I get a multicolored image on my monitor, but then nothing.

I have read several posts about converting from B+ to v2, but none seem to address in any detail what I should do when the B+ SD card does not boot up.  One post (indented below) indicated that I should look at the kernel.  Sorry but I'm too much of a beginner to full understand what that meant and what I should be doing :-(

[Can you use a micro SD card from raspberry pi B+ on the raspberry pi 2 model B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/can-you-use-a-micro-sd-card-from-raspberry-pi-b-on-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b)

> However, be sure to make it clear that you have checked for the
>   correct kernel and include the kernel= line from /boot/config.txt, if
>   any.

Repeating myself, when I put in the old Pi B+ SD card into the Pi v2 I get the multicolored screen and then nothing, the red LED in on solid and the other one is off.

***edit: 19 July*** Additional info:  The SD card I'm working with was built up from a NOOBS when I bought my first two Raspberry Pi B+ units in July 2014.  When I look at that SD card on my Windows PC I do not see a config.txt, nor a kernel.img file. Should I create a config.txt file?  Where can I get a copy of the kernel17.img specified in the above reference?

If I insert a NOOBS SD it boots up ok, but I would really like to not have to totally reconfigure this new unit.

Thanks for any help....RDK

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading from Pi to Pi2](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/upgrading-from-pi-to-pi2)

Answer (score 2):

I thought this wasn't possible because the CPU is completely different; notice `armv6l` vs `armv7l` in the output below.

However, I found [this other post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/can-you-use-a-micro-sd-card-from-raspberry-pi-b-on-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b) that states otherwise; haven't tried myself, but worth a shot!

RPi B+:

```
pi@tribecapi ~ $ uname -a
Linux tribecapi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

RPi 2:

```
pi@mediapi ~ $ uname -a
Linux mediapi 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: That other post is correct ;)  All of the A/B/+ *userland* stuff will work on Pi 2 since ARMv7 is backward compatible with ARMv6, and I think the firmware is the same as well, but there are differences in the kernel (which is compiled for ARMv7); if you don't indicate a kernel in `config.txt` and there's a `kernel7.img`, the bootloader should deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

You should run `sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade"` on your B+. That worked for me. Then put the SD card into your Pi 2.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is wrong.  `update` will upgrade the package listing, and `upgrade` will update the packages.  You aren't updating distribution packages with this set of commands.